# Development Economics Minor for CS Major

Tags: graduate-school, computer-science, major, minor

I am an undergrad CS Major and am looking to minor in Development Economics, basically economics for understanding challenges created by world poverty (this is the only form of an economics minor that my school offers). I have seen several posts here regarding what a good minor for CS majors is and most of the of responses say to take what you are genuinely interested in that has a good chance of helping you career-wise in the future. I plan on to going to grad school *probably for ML* and I wanted to know if I should pick a different minor knowing this. My school doesn't offer a statistics minor (for grad school ML) and I also want to minor in something I am genuinely interested in - the last thing I want to do is get stuck doing a minor I hate for the possibility of grad school. Also, I am also doing undergrad research this upcoming semester; would undergrad research or a specific minor be more valuable to a grad school?

Comment: All this is highyl specific to you. Play your strenghts, and at the same time get a broad enough (better: broad as possible) fundamental education.

Comment: Why not mathematics?

Comment: @Buffy I am not really interested by it. I feel like the stuff I will do in grad school has to allign with both my genuine interests along what will hold up career-wise; my thinking was with a major in CS and minor in Econ, I could research maybe modeling global economies using ML or something like that

Comment: I suggested mathematics for its relevance to ML, actually. But you get to choose. Don't obsess too much over it. Pick something you like.

Comment: Look at the course list for the dev econ minor. You could probably gain the same knowledge they provide by reading a micro and macro economics textbook, listening to the [CGD podcast](https://www.cgdev.org/cgd-podcast), and reading a few books by Peter Singer. As @Buffy suggested, a math minor would *greatly* benefit you if you end up doing ML in grad school.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the others that it makes sense to explore what interests you at this stage. CS is already a strong major and you will be forced to specialize more later on. A few points in favor:

- I don't think anyone pays too much attention to your minor, to be honest. I would weigh the transcript more heavily than the precise name of the major or minor, so if your coursework shows a strong foundation in math/stats/CS classes then I see no problem with having an additional interest.
- Economic thinking is an interesting and new perspective in and of itself which could benefit you as an intellectual. I think it would broaden your horizons and give you an approach to modeling that many CS majors won't have. The intersection of econ + CS is also growing in popularity.
- There is a decent community of emerging around computing for development. Some resources you might find useful are:
  https://acmcompass.org/
  https://didl.berkeley.edu/
  https://crcs.seas.harvard.edu/
  https://www.ml.cmu.edu/academics/joint-phd-mlpp.html
  Maybe you can find some profiles that look like yours for inspiration.

That said, I agree with the commenters that math and statistics will be very valuable to you if you pursue ML at a higher level. So it would be good to load up on these courses now if you plan to move on to a competitive graduate degree.

Also, if by "graduate school" you mean PhD, I believe research would be much more important than adding a single line to your CV as a minor. Perhaps you could do some research at the intersection of computer science and development?